# How to develop regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in JavaScript which contains all alphabet, `%` and  `_`. I have written this regex for that which is not working fine. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my Regex:

```
^[^.<>(){}'&@#]*$
```

Comment: Why do you use a character class to exclude a random set of symbols instead of "translating" your actual requirement into an regular expression?

Comment: Also, "not working fine" is not a useful description of a problem. What do you want to do, what is the text, what do you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex you are looking for:

```js
const regex = /[A-Za-z_%]/g
```

**Explanation:**
`/.../` - Javascript regex literal syntax
`[...]` - A group of possible matches (exp. A or B or C etc.)
`A-Za-z` - Every English letter. (Upper & lower case)
`_` - Underscore char
`%` - The % char.
`g` - Global flag suffix to keep matching every res.

You can try it in [Regex tester](https://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: but if You add numbers it is also taking that, that has to be avoided.

Comment: It's working fine, but I am using this regex in angular Validators.pattern("/[A-Za-z_%]/g"), in that case it doesn't work properly, can you just let me know why?

Comment: @Ashwanikumar It's not a String, it is a regular expression. It's literals are the forward-slashes `/PATTERN/`, whereas the String literals are the quotes `'String'`/`"String"`.

Comment: @Ashwanikumar what Oskar said is correct but I'm not sure it's clear. Remove the "" and use it like: Validators.pattern(/[A-Za-z_%]/g)

Comment: I Added like this Validators.pattern("[A-Za-z_%]") it's working fine Thankyou.